# Use express-session with NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, express-session

I'm in the middle of making a login system, with nextJS, and Mysql. I wanted to use sessions to login the user, but don't know how to combine `express-session` with `NextJS`. My question is, can `express-session` be used with `NextJS`, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express-Session is a middleware for Express (it runs on the Express server.)

The best you can do is serve your NextJS application through the Express app, and use the Middleware to handle sessions.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: I decided to go with `iron-session`, but I accept this as an answer, as it answers my question.

Comment: What about if you use it with the [next-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect) library? I am using it that way and it is working.